# Sqoop export from hive to teradata does not work with timestamp field

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop

I am trying to export a file from hive which has one field as timestamp (`'2016-05-21 02:00:00'`) to teradata. 
The datatype in teradata is `timestamp(0)` which can expect a similar format.

When i try to export it using sqoop, it gives string to timestamp conversion error.
Any workarounds this would greatly help.

**Note:**

- `String` in hive to `Varchar(256)` in teradata works.
- `String` in hive to `timestamp(0)` in teradata fails.
- `Timestamp` in hive to `timestamp(0)` in teradata fails.

**Logs :**

```
16/07/12 12:24:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/07/12 12:24:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1467306662019_8607_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unparseable date: "2016-07-11 22:36:55"
    at com.teradata.connector.common.converter.ConnectorDataTypeConverter$StringFMTTZToTimestampTZ.convert(ConnectorDataTypeConverter.java:1679)
    at com.teradata.connector.teradata.converter.TeradataConverter.convert(TeradataConverter.java:143)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorOutputFormat$ConnectorFileRecordWriter.write(ConnectorOutputFormat.java:106)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorOutputFormat$ConnectorFileRecordWriter.write(ConnectorOutputFormat.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorMMapper.map(ConnectorMMapper.java:129)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorMMapper.run(ConnectorMMapper.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

Comment: what is your export command?

Comment: sqoop export -D mapred.job.queue.name=TestBatch -D mapred.output.compress=true -D mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec --connect jdbc:teradata://xxx.yy.zz.fff/Database=dev_stg --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager --username test --password test --table dev_stg.bag --export-dir "/dwh/data/event/bag/" --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --null-string '\N' --null-non-string '\N'

Comment: It worked perfectly from **hive's timestamp to teradata's timestamp(6)**           _(which is default )_. Can you rerun the command with `-verbose` in the end for extended logs?

Comment: Also, you should use `--input-null-string '\N' --input-null-non-string '\N'` as per the [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_4)

Comment: So in hive i should have it as a timestamp field with the format of '2016-07-11 12:00:00' and in teradata i should have the timestamp defined as timestamp(6). Is that what you mean?

Comment: This is what I tried and it worked fine for me. Tomorrow I will try with timestamp(0) and let you know if  its successful. Meanwhile if you edit your question with extended logs, it will help me to understand the issue

Comment: I just pasted my logs. Hive timestamp to tereadata timestamp(6) does not work and it gives me the same error that i pasted in the logs.

Comment: Are your hive table columns delimited by CTRL +A ('\001')? "2016-07-11 22:36:55" is os timestamp datatype or string?

Comment: Yes my hive table columns are delimited by CTRL A. And i am inserting into this table from another table. I am selecting the timestamp field as follows:

cast(from_unixtime(cast(startMillis/1000 as bigint),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as TIMESTAMP) as eventtime

startMillis is a string in Table A. I am converting that to a timestamp value in Table B. And i am trying to export Table B into teradata.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117133/discussion-between-dev--and-austin).

Comment: Is there a solution identified?

Answer (score 1):

Teradata column should be in "TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE" format. It is working fine for me.